# How to raise an Exception and still continue the main code in Python

Tags: python, exception

Given the following simple example:

```
while True:

    readme = input("Write here something:")

    if readme == "":

        raise Exception("That was empty!")
```

(1) How can the main code / loop continue to work after an Exception has been thrown?  (2) And if we simultaneously run another thread, how can we catch the Exception in there?

Edit: is it possible to do this without having a try/except block inside the loop?

Comment: If you want your code to continue after an exception was thrown, you need to catch the exception. Go read https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: I realized I may have to update my question. In the loop, I do not wish to use a try / except block. Is it possible to work around that?

Comment: Please see also part (2) of the question.

Comment: So you want to raise an exception, not catch it, and have your code continue anway? I'm not sure what your asking for makes any sense.

Comment: This is more of a theoretical question than a practical one, hence the simplification of the code. I would be interested to know if that is possible to do. I put the question in 2 parts, so you would understand better what I am after. Please read further than just question 1...

Answer (score 0):

Without using the try/catch it is not possible in python. When we call a function in python and it raises a exception, the exceptions is propagated to the caller function and it continues.

If you do not handle the the exception anywhere in the above chain, interpreter just throw it out to the user.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible with try/except.

Try making a function like so:

```
from inspect import currentframe,getframeinfo
def Raise(ex):

    cf = currentframe()
    #Get the line
    line=cf.f_back.f_lineno
    print('Traceback:\n'+ex+'\nin line '+str(line))
    wait=input('Press Enter to continue excecution.')
```

And then call:

```
myexception('That was empty!)
```

For example (from the example):

```
from inspect import currentframe,getframeinfo

    def Raise(ex):
    cf = currentframe()
    #Get the line
    line=cf.f_back.f_lineno
    print('Traceback:\n'+ex+'\nin line '+str(line))
    wait=input('Press Enter to continue excecution.')

readme = input("Write here something:")
if readme == "":
    Raise("That was empty!")
```